# Scraping tags that have spaces in class names php

Tags: php, curl, dom, web-scraping

Here I have an html div tag with class name that has space in it.

```
<div data-marker="music-track-title" class="music-track__title text--single-line size-e"> No Vanguard Revival (Radio 1 Session, 16 May 2018) </div>
```

I tried getting information out of this tag with php curl and dom help, but it just returns nothing.

Heres code that i have written so far:(Not working)

```
<?php 
    include_once 'includes/db.inc.php';
    include_once 'includes/simple_html_dom.php';
    include_once 'includes/curl_init.php';
    $yesterday = date("Y/m/d", strtotime( '-1 days' ) );
    $a=NULL;
    $html=curl_get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/music/tracks/find/radio1/'.$yesterday.'/12AM');
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom = str_get_html($html);
    $myList=NULL;
    $songs=$dom->find('.music-track__top music-track__top--list');
?>
```

How to get information from div tag with spaces in its class name. Using php curl, Dom.

Comment: Is there only one div tag having spaces in class name? Or there could be more.

Comment: There are more i just posted one to show an example.

Comment: So need to get all tags that have spaces in class name?

Comment: There are more but now my goal is to get information out of this one.

Comment: Your don't need the line `$dom = new DOMDocument();` if your using simplehtmldom.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="music-track__title";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
$node = null;
foreach ($nodes as $element) {
    if ($element->getAttribute('class') == "music-track__title text--single-line size-e") {
        $node = $element;
        break;
    }
}
```

Variable `$elements` will contains the list of tags that have spaces in class name.

Comment: I don't think the aim is to find tags with spaces in the class attribute, they just want to find a tag which in effect has 2 specific classes.

Comment: Yes Nigel comment is correct.